# Create log likelihood function for three classes for SEIR modelling

Tags: r, predictive-models, modeling, likelihood

I am working on SEIR model for measles data which has the following variables and sample observations.

```
PN      NAME        FN  HN  AGE   SEX  PRO    ERU  CL  DEAD  IFTO  SI  C PR CA NI GE TD   TM   HNX  HNY
  1        Mueller  41  61   7.00  2  11.21  11.25  1   0.00   45  10  0  4  4  3  1  0   0.0   57   40
  2        Mueller  41  61   6.00  2  11.23  11.27  1   0.00   45  12  0  4  4  3  1  3  40.3   57   40
  3        Mueller  41  61   4.00  2  11.28  12.02  0   0.00  172   9  0  4  4  3  2  1  40.5   57   40
  4        Seibold  61  62  13.00  1  11.27  11.28  2   0.00  180  10  0  1  1  1  1  3  40.7   66   41
```

The data dictionary is following.

```
# PN    patient no.
# NAME  patient name
# FN    family index
# HN    house no.
# AGE   age in years
# SEX   0 = unknown
#       1 = male
#       2 = female
# PRO   date of prodromes (month.day)
# ERU   date of rash      (month.day)
# CL    class: 0 = preschool
#              1 = 1st class
#              2 = 2nd class
# DEAD  0.00 = survived
#       month.day of death
# IFTO  no. of patient who is the putative source
#       of infection according to H. Oesterle (0 = unknown)
# SI    serialinterval = no. of days between dates of prodromes
#       of infection source and infected person
# C     complications: 0 = no complicatons
#                      1 = bronchopneumonia
#                      2 = severe bronchitis
#                      3 = lobar pneumonia
#                      4 = pseudocroup
#                      5 = cerebral edema
# PR    duration of prodromes in days
# CA    number of cases in family
# NI    number of initial cases
# GE    generation number of the case
# TD    day of max. fever (days after rush)
# TM    max. fever (degree celsius)
# HNX   x coordinate of house (in 2.5m units)
# HNY   y coordinate of house (in 2.5m units)
```

Here, the column classes represents the class (0,1 and 2).

I want to calculate the max log likelihood using a function, based on the classes (0,1,2), based on classes it can be called as the "classroom" model.

First, individuals behave the same as before in terms of the exposed period and the infectious period. That part of the model is the what I have done.

The new part is the transmission part. In the original model,

S(t+1) ~ Binomial(S(t), q^I(t)).

In the classrooms model, I have to consider two parameters, q and qc where each individual is in class 1, class 2 or class 0 (= pre-school).

I wan to consider S_k(t) and I_k(t) for the number of susceptibles and infectives in class k.

The first thing I need is to write a function to evaluate these quantities.
Please note that S(t) = S_0(t) + S_1(t) + S_2(t), etc.

The idea is that qc is the probability that a susceptible in class 1 (or 2) avoids infection from a single infective in the same class. Such a susceptible can also be infected by infectives in the other two classes, but with probability q.

This means that (assuming the usual independence)

S_1(t+1) ~ Binomial (S_1(t), (qc)^I_1(t) q^{I_0(t)+I_2(t)})

Since a susceptible in class 1 remains susceptible if and only if they avoid infection from (i) the I_1(t) infectives in class 1 and (ii) the other infectives in the population, of which there are I_0(t) + I_2(t).

There is a similar expression for S_2(t+1).

S_0(t+1) is slightly different, since class 0 children are not at school. So,

S_0(t+1) ~ Binomial(S_0(t), q^I(t))

where I(t) = I_0(t) + I_1(t) + I_2(t).

So I am struggling to write a function for the likelihood (or log-likelihood), which now is a function of two parameters (q and qc). I can use optim in R to find the maximum.

Here, is my previous log likelihood function without considering the classes.

```
ress=rep(0,50)
likelihood<-function(q)
{
  for(i in 1:49){
  ress[i+1]=(Current_dayStats$St[i]-Current_dayStats$St[i+1])*log(1-q^(Current_dayStats$It[i]))+(Current_dayStats$St[i+1])*log(q^(Current_dayStats$It[i]))

  }
  # ress[is.infinite(ress)]<-0
  # ress[is.nan(ress)]<-0
  # ress
   return (sum(ress))

}

q=seq(0.1,0.9,0.1)
optim(par<-q,fn=likelihood)
q=seq(0.01,0.99,0.01)
which.max(sapply(q,likelihood))
MLE<-q[which.max(sapply(q,likelihood))]
MLE
plot(q,sapply(q, likelihood),type = "l")
```

Current_dayStats is a dataframe as the following. Also, 50 is the number of days. Total population size is 180.

Please provide your kind suggestions, how can I move forward with it.

```
  It Rt Et  St
1  2  1  3 180
2  2  1  5 179
3  2  1  6 178
4  2  1  7 178
5  2  1  7 176
6  2  1  7 176
```